# Нужно ли добавить двоеточие перед кавычками (цитатой, надписью)?

Tags: пунктуация

А в аэропорту я видел тонганца, футболку которого украшала фотография пожилой женщины; сверху было написано «Спи спокойно, мама», а внизу – две даты.

Comment: В прошлый раз Людмила же вам всё прекрасно объяснила, в каких случаях ставится двоеточие, в каких нет.

Comment: @ Niemand Вот(ниже) мне дали ещё вариант - о чём Людмила не писала. Значит не зря спрашивал.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны два варианта оформления:

1) **Прямая речь внутри слов автора:**

*А в аэропорту я видел тонганца, футболку которого украшала фотография пожилой женщины; сверху было написано: **«Спи спокойно, мама»,** а внизу – две даты.*

2) **Прямая речь как член предложения (дополнение):**

*А в аэропорту я видел тонганца, футболку которого украшала фотография пожилой женщины; сверху было написано **«Спи спокойно, мама»,** а внизу – две даты.*

**Пояснение:**

1) Грамота.ру предлагает **два равноправных варианта на выбор автора.** Варианты имеют разную **интонацию**: при постановке двоеточия делается предупредительная пауза.

```
Вопрос № 254182
```

*Простой вопрос **«Откуда берутся дети?**» часто приводит родителей в замешательство.*

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

*Простой вопрос: **«Откуда берутся дети?»** – часто приводит родителей в замешательство.*

Или так:

*Простой вопрос **«Откуда берутся дети?**» часто приводит родителей в замешательство.*

2) **Но согласуется ли это с правилами Розенталя или ПАС?**  Как я думаю, вполне согласуется.

**ПАС:** ...если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания ставятся по условиям авторского предложения.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Но это если прямая речь **включается**, но она может и не включаться. Решение зависит от разных факторов: от распространенности дословного высказывания, от желания автора его выделить в отдельную фразу и т.д.